# Sending List/Array of Complex Object from Android to vb.net web service

Tags: android, vb.net, web-services, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to send an array/ list of Complex objects using ksoap from android to vb.net webservice. I can send complex object but the list is giving me trouble.

This is the android code

```
private class SampleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // if you want, start progress dialog here
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String webResponse = "";
            try {
                final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.org/";
                final String URL = "http://192.168.1.103:8081/MySampleService.asmx";
                final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.org/SampleWS";
                final String METHOD_NAME = "SampleWS";

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                 List<MediSenseLog> logs =  new ArrayList<MediSenseLog>();

                 MediSenseLog log1 = new MediSenseLog();
                    log1.setID(Integer.parseInt("1"));
                    log1.setLogDate("2014-05-13");

                     MediSenseLog log2 = new MediSenseLog();
                        log1.setID(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                        log1.setLogDate("2014-05-14");

                    logs.add(log1);
                    logs.add(log2);

                    SoapObject soapLogs = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "logs");

                    for (MediSenseLog i : logs){
                        soapLogs.addProperty("MediSenseLog", i);
                    }
                    request.addSoapObject(soapLogs);


                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "MediSenseLog",new MediSenseLog().getClass());

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                Log.d("HTTP REQUEST ",androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
                Log.d("HTTP RESPONSE", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                Log.d("ComplexWS", response.toString());
                webResponse = response.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return webResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Synchonization Completed...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("ComplexWS","return val is "+result);

        }
    }
```

This is the .net code

```
 Public Class MediSenseLog
    Public ID As Integer
    Public LogDate As String

End Class

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function SampleWS(ByVal logs As MediSenseLog()) As String
    Return logs(1).LogDate.ToString()
End Function
```

This is the request using requestdump

```
 <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <Sample xmlns="http://sample.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
            <n0:logs i:type="n0:logs" xmlns:n0="http://sample.org/">
                <MediSenseLog i:type="n0:MediSenseLog">
                    <ID i:type="d:int">2</ID>
                    <LogDate i:type="d:string">2014-05-14</LogDate>
                </MediSenseLog>
                <MediSenseLog i:type="n0:MediSenseLog">
                    <ID i:type="d:int">0</ID>
                    <LogDate i:null="true" />
                </MediSenseLog>
            </n0:logs>
        </Sample>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

This is the response using response dump

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <SampleResponse xmlns="http://sample.org/">
        <SampleResult />
    </SampleResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The return Value is blank.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Please send me your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error

just change this

```
 log1.setID(Integer.parseInt("2"));
log1.setLogDate("2014-05-14");
```

to

```
log2.setID(Integer.parseInt("2"));
log2.setLogDate("2014-05-14");
```